# wordpress change to friendly URL with variable using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I have a wordpress site with a page template and 1 variable call uid (user id) , and I wanna change it to friendly url.

from

```
http://localhost/forum/edit-profile/?uid=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/forum/edit-profile/1
```

or

```
http://localhost/forum/edit-profile/uid/1
```

P/S: wordpress already has a .htaccess file , i just wanna add some additional codes to this.

I tried these solutions, but they are not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forumengine/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forumengine/index.php [L]

RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} uid=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/$ $1/%1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/(\d+)$ $1/?uid=$2&no-redir [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` rules

```
RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} uid=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/$ $1/%1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/(\d+)$ $1/?uid=$2&no-redir [NC,QSA,L]
```

This would redirect `/forum/edit-profile/?uid=1` to `/forum/edit-profile/1` and back.

***EDIT** : (with wordpress rules they should go like)*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /forumengine/

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
  RewrieCond %{QUERY_STRING} uid=([^&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/$ $1/%1 [R=301,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
  RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/(\d+)$ $1/?uid=$2&no-redir [NC,QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /forumengine/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it not working i mean from /forum/edit-profile/?uid=1 to /forum/edit-profile/1.Thanks 
This the code in .htaccess file

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forumengine/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forumengine/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/edit-profile)/(\d+)$ $1/?uid=$2  [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: @NTThái Your custom rules should come before the WordPress rules.